# PS3 games on different systems

Tags: ps3

So MLB The Show just game out.  Me and my dad both enjoy playing it and we buy it every year.  Now that I am away at college (I got my own PS3 system) I would like to only buy it once.  Can I do this via PSN.  In other words, I know that I can download on two machines, but I have seen that you have to be logged in under the same account, and you have to wait at least 24 hours between playing on seperate systems.

So an I correct in assuming that we will not be able to play at the same time.  If I am playing and he signs in (same account), will I get booted from the game, or just the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

While PSN users can be logged into one system of a type at a certain time (i.e. can only be logged once from any PS3), a game downloaded into an activated console will be available to other users on the same system, so you should be able to play with your father, as long as both consoles are activated with the owner account, the game is downloaded to both and you're logged in **with different accounts**.

Comment: So tell your dad to make his own psn account after downloading the game and it will be all good.

Comment: Can I play it if I am not connected to the internet?

Comment: @yankeefan11 online? I doubt it :) Offline? Yes

Comment: Thats awesome.  Pretty good deal

Comment: You could both play online as long as you're using different accounts. You may need to download an online pass for the game with the same account before the online portion would be available, though.